# How can I vertically center text and a button in a list group header?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have the following header in a list group

```css
.list-group-header{
  border: solid black 1px;
}

button{
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-group-header clearfix">
  <div class="pull-left">
  Open Issues
  </div>

  <button class="pull-right">
  New Issue
  </button>
</div>
```

I would like a bootstrap way of vertically centering the header "Open Issues" with the button

Answer (score 0):

You may set the ***line-height***:

```css
.list-group-header{
  border: solid black 1px;
}

.pull-left {
  line-height: 50px;
}
button{
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="list-group-header clearfix">
    <div class="pull-left">
        Open Issues
    </div>

    <button class="pull-right">
        New Issue
    </button>
</div>
```